# PHP/SQL - How to manipulate spatial Point SQL data type in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, coordinates

I am trying to calculate earth distance between two points stored in a Point type SQL column.

Users can specify their home city and my application will allow them to search different things around them.

My problem is, with a query, I fetch all columns relative to the home city of the user and store them into variables. Though I have no idea how to manipulate SQL Point data type in PHP.

When I write this :

```
var_dump($coordinates); // city coordinates that MySQL will fetch
```

PHP will tell me it's a string while displaying unreadable characters.

I tried to fetch longitude and latitude with this SQL statement and store them in variables :

```
'SELECT ST_X(coordinates) AS longitude, ST_Y(coordinates) AS latitude FROM cities';
```

But this query

```
SELECT * FROM table a 
    INNER JOIN cities b ON a.cityId = b.id
WHERE (acos(sin(radians(ST_Y(b.coordinates))) 
      * sin(radians(*ANY_VALUE*)) 
      + cos(radians(ST_Y(b.coordinates))) 
      * cos(radians(*ANY_VALUE*)) 
      * cos(radians(ST_X(b.coordinates)) 
      - radians(*ANY_VALUE*))) 
      * 6378137) <= 50000
```

Will not work with those variables while it does work if I enter it manually in PhpMyAdmin with any coordinates.

Any tip?

Comment: Is your DB encoding different to your PHP SQL API encoding? You can define `charset` when you create an instance of the `PDO`. - If you're using that.

Comment: API is encoded in UTF-8 while DB encoding is UTF-8MB4

Comment: Can you show us what `will not work` means? What does `print_r()` give you for your rows? Are you getting errors? Show us how your code looks and the query output in your actual DB. Consider making your environment (minimal but complete and verifiable) in a [dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/) for us to use.